# How to wrap tile title text on start tile of windows phone 8 cordova app?

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am using 
 -

- cordova 3.5
- windows phone 8 OS
- Device Nokia Lumia 1320 with windows 8 OS

[image]

In the above screen shot of start screen of windows phone. Please check the tile which is marked with red square. I want to either wrap title text to display it on multiple lines or show ellipses(..) in title text before it goes out of boundary. My example title text is "How to wrap tile title in windows phone 8".

I do not want to write any native custom code.

**Is it possible to achieve it using cordova configuration or configuration in WMAppManifest.xml.?**